# Any way to resolve performance issues with ExpansionTile in flutter?

Tags: performance, flutter, build, flutter-layout

So I'm currently making a list with Expansion tiles and while analyzing performance through dev tools, I noticed something. When expanding a tile, the build numbers for the title text go insanely high. Each time a tile is pressed, build numbers go up by about 17. After some testing(done in a debug build as I can't track widget rebuilds in performance mode), I realized that this is a problem with `ExpansionTile`. It actually does make sense for there to be this problem, since the standard arrow in the expansion tile is animated. So for every frame of the animation, the title text is refreshed along with it. Unfortunately when working with expansion tiles in a list builder, it just adds to the degraded performance. Is there some possible work around to make everything more efficient, or is this just a drawback of using `ExpansionTile`?

As a side note: I am aware that debug build mode isn't great for measuring performance, but I do get the same frame drops for the most part compared to profile build mode.

Just for more information: I am making an app which compiles different lists for several parsed JSON files. Ideally I use a list builder (like `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` or `ListView.builder`) since the info is varying according to each JSON file. I opted for `ExpansionTile` for use in the lists since it would make them less cluttered and more manageable for the user.

I hope I structured this well enough. Thanks for any possible feedback.

Comment: hey I was having the same problem have resolved it?